# DRAM/DDR energy consumption

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, sdram

I have some questions about the origin of energy consumption in DRAM based memories/systems. In *Mark Horowitz* paper *Computing’s Energy Problem
(and what we can do about it)* the author breaks down the sources of energy loss in modern computing systems. The most striking of the results, is the huge energy cost of outside DRAM memory accesses. Unfortunately, the author doesn't explain how they obtained the numbers. In my minds, several factors can contribute to DRAMs high energy consumption:

- Its rows need to be refreshed every so often.
- As DDR interfaces are high speed, the high clock rate means we need higher currents to fill the capacitance of the PCB quickly.
- Lastly, and perhaps most importantly, DRAM is not on the same chip as the logic (e.g. CPU). Thus the capacitance of the PCB, IO pads etc.. are much greater then for any memory that is on the same chip as the logic.

So the question here is, am I right about these reasons? Which of these factors contributes the most?

Thank you for any answers or thoughts.

Comment: Yes, and the termination resistors. For DDR3L (1.35V) with 50 ohms termination, that is 1.35mA, or 18.23mW for each line in the address/control bus, even idle.